# yii2-multiple-input I can't get current row

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, widget, tabular

I am working with the [yii2-multiple-input](https://github.com/unclead/yii2-multiple-input), all good when deleting an item iam using the javascript event `beforeDeleteRow` like below.

```
jQuery('#wtabularbotellas').on('beforeDeleteRow',function(e, row, currentIndex) {
   // This throw the number of rows instead how do I get the current Index? 
   alert(currentIndex);    
});
```

But I can't capture the ID number of the row. I tried to do it using the `row` object and the `currentIndex` variable, without result since the latter only returns the number of rows and not the index I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `currentIndex` you are using is actually the current index the multiple input container is at.

For example if you have `5` inputs and you delete `1` the current index will be `4`, it isn't the index of the deleted row, so that means the `currentIndex` is not the actual index of the row but the total number of rows in the container, and if you are expecting that if you delete the 3rd row out of total `5` rows it should return 3/2 (depending on the starting index from `0` or `1`) then you are wrong.

I cant guess what you actually want to accomplish by getting the actual row id of the element/row, although you can do that but before you do you need to understand something.

Consider the following list as the rows and there index inside the container respectively.

[image]

```
| IDX | Element | ID  
| 1   | input   | email-1
| 2   | input   | email-2
| 3   | input   | email-3
| 4   | input   | email-4
| 5   | input   | email-5
```

if you delete the last row, the new indexes will be same as before which should be logically ok.

```
| IDX | Element | ID  
| 1   | input   | email-1
| 2   | input   | email-2
| 3   | input   | email-3
| 4   | input   | email-4
```

but if you remove the first row, and you are expecting that after deleting the first row the rest of the indexes will keep there previous indexing like below,

```
| IDX | Element | ID  
| 2   | input   | email-2
| 3   | input   | email-3
| 4   | input   | email-4
| 5   | input   | email-5
```

**Nopes**, after delete the index will be reset, and if you delete the first element every time, you will always get the index 1.

So if you still want to get the row number of the row that was deleted you should use the `row` parameter and the `.index()` function the `row` parameter will have the object of the row that is about to be deleted.

**Note: The following examples are using the basic single column, adjust your script accordingly**

```
$js = <<<JS
    jQuery('#wtabularbotellas').on('beforeDeleteRow',function(e, row,currentIndex) {
       //the index of the row removed 
       let removedIndex= row.index();

       //id of the input inside 
       let inputId = row.find(':input').attr('id');
       console.log("Index removed====>"+removedIndex, "Input id of the removed row input====>"+inputId);
    });
JS;

$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Comment: Thanks Very much. I want o get the "real index"  to validate the operation by ajax . For example if user try delete and this row has childs records, I want to prevent this before the user  post the form, and show some error message.

Comment: You should **not use the HTML index** instead you should use the input `data` attribute like  `data-has-child="true"` when creating the input initially, and when deleting get the index with the mentioned approach as above just change the `row.find(':input').attr('id');`  to `row.find(':input').data('has-child');` and deny the deletion right away or allow it @TomasGrecioRamirez dont go with the ajax call when using the events as you wont be able to return `true` or `false` in that case